# Types Being Camouflaged in WCF Service Proxy?

Tags: wcf, types, proxy

I have three projects in my Visual Studio Solution:

1. “Core” contains a bunch of types.
2. "WCF Service” uses all of the types in “Core” in service methods.
3. “Test Client” is a test client app and just has a bunch of test
   code.

When I consume my WCF Service in my Test Client, everything looks and works great.  The proxy for the service methods are generated so I can pass parameters with the correct type like `Core.BusinessObj`.  However, when I consume that same WCF Service from Core, the proxy being generated requires those same service methods to pass like this: `ServiceProxy.BusinessObj`.  This is causing a problem since I want to create object of type `Core.BusinessObj` and pass them to my service no matter where that service is being consumed.  I am sure this has something to do with referencing my WCF Service within the same project where all the types are defined, but can’t figure out how to get the namespaces correctly identified.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong - that's just the way WCF works!

When you build the service, you define the service methods and the parameters (and their data types) that those services will expect. This is packaged up on the server side and typically exposed via metadata exchange (MEX).

When the client comes along, and creates the client side proxy for your service, all it can rely on are the bits and pieces in the metadata - description of the service methods (names, parameters), and the description of what the XML will look like that travels between client and server.

Client and server in WCF are talking to one another via **serialized (XML) messages** - there is no other connection - no direct link or anything. So all the client can do is to make sure his data types that he creates based on the service metadata will **serialize** into the same XML as the service expects (and that he's able to deserialize the XML messages from the server).

The client creates **new client-side types** that will have the same "XML footprint" (the same structured in serialized XML) - but that's all he can do. That's why you get types that look very similar - but they **are different** (typically in a different namespace). That's also the reason why you shouldn't have any functionality (code) in your server-side data contracts - you cannot serialize functionality over XML messages .....

Now, if you control both ends of the communication wire (both the server and the client) and you write both of them in .NET, then you can take a "shortcut" to re-use the types. Basically, you need to do what you did - put all the types and interfaces into a separate assembly ("Core"). Next: **before** you create your WCF proxy on the client side, make sure the client project **references** that "Core" assembly. When you create the WCF client-side proxy with the "Core" assembly referenced, you can tell WCF to "reuse types in referenced assemblies" - if you have this option on (it's on by default), then if your referenced assemblies already contain a data type that matches the needs of the WCF client, then that type (from your "Core" assembly) will be reused (instead of a new one created).

[image]
*WCF - Add Service Reference - Advanced Options*

Comment: Thank you.  I think I need to reengineer my project.  I have logic built into the types I am sending accross the wire.  By including the assembly with my types proior to building the client side proxy, I got the result I was looking for.  Now I just have to rewrite everything :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Core.BusinessObj is Serializable

(Example, assuming its for .NET 4)

```
[Serializable]
public class BusinessObj
```

Make sure that your service is building fine (with no errors)

Update the service reference (After successfully building of the service)

Comment: Everything is already marked as Serializable - othersise the test client would not be able to consume and use the service.  I'm only having the issue when consuming the service from the Core project (where the types are defined).

Comment: Rather than using `[Serializable]`, it's more likely that he should be using `[DataContract]`.

Answer (score 0):

I built a solution as you described. And it passes the test without any problem.
In my solution there are 3 projects now

1. Core
2. WCFService
3. TestClient

Project Core has one class "BusinessObj"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Core
{
    [Serializable]
    public class BusinessObj
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Project WCFService has a WebService named "Service1" 
(reference to Core has been added)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WCFService
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public Core.BusinessObj GetBusinessObj()
        {
            return new Core.BusinessObj()
            {
                id = 1
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Test project, TestClient has one unit test "UnitTest1"
(reference to Core has been added)
(service reference to Service1 has been added)

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using TestClient.ServiceReference;
using Core;

namespace TestClient
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Service1Client ServiceProxy = new Service1Client();

            BusinessObj x = ServiceProxy.GetBusinessObj();
            Assert.IsTrue(x.id == 1, "Something's wrong dude!!!");

        }
    }
}
```

> **I think "using Core;" is missing from your TestClient**

Comment: Romi, the problem is not with TestClient - it works perfectly.  My issues is when I try to use the WCFService from within Core.  For example, in your example above, the issue comes in when the service is called from inside BusinessObj.  The proxy is generated using the ServiceName.BusinessObj instead of Core.BusinessObj.